# sencha touch RadioGroup not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Does RadioGroup works properly in sencha touch ?
Example :

```
    var myRadioGroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
        id: 'myGroup',
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Single Column',
        // Arrange radio buttons into three columns, distributed vertically
        columns: 3,
        vertical: true,
        items: [
            {boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1'},
            {boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true},
            {boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb', inputValue: '3'},
            {boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb', inputValue: '4'},
            {boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb', inputValue: '5'},
            {boxLabel: 'Item 6', name: 'rb', inputValue: '6'}
        ]
    });

    var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        title: 'Results',
        style:"margin:50px 0 0 10px;",
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox', // Arrange child items vertically
            align: 'stretch',//, // Each takes up full width
            padding: 55
        },
        defaults: {
            labelWidth: '85%',
            labelWrap: true,
            labelAlign: 'right'
        },
        items:[{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'RadioGroup',
            items:myRadioGroup
        }]

    });

    Ext.viewport.add(resultsPanel);
```

This generates the following error :
[ERR] C2008: Requirement had no matching files (Ext.form.RadioGroup) -- C:\xampp\htdocs\testRadio\app.js:17:30.

Does anyone have an idea ,i tried updating app.json (not working ) ,also i searched for RadioGroup.js in touch/src/form/ but did not find it .

Answer (score 0):

Sencha don't have radio group field , It has radio field only.

refer this. http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.Radio

for implementing Radio group give same name to all radio field: 
ex:

```
   var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'color',
        value: 'red',
        label: 'Red',
        checked: true
    },
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'color',
        value: 'green',
        label: 'Green'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'color',
        value: 'blue',
        label: 'Blue'
    }
 ]
});
```